# Android loading string array into activity using background thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice

I have an activity where the user enters a value in an `EditText` and I search a string array that I have defined in a xml file for a match. Each time the user changes the text I look for a match. When I start this activity I load the string array resource.

Should the loading of the array and the match finding occur in a background thread?

From what I understand I can use an `AsyncTask` which I am familiar with or a `IntentService` which I have no experience with. Would `IntentService` be overkill? What is ideal for this operation?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is possible to accomplish the same task with either an AsyncTask or a Service however usually one is better suited to a task than the other.

AsyncTasks are designed for once-off time-consuming tasks that cannot be run of the UI thread. A common example is fetching/processing data when a button is pressed.

Services are designed to be continually running in the background. In the example above of fetching data when a button is pressed, you could start a service, let it fetch the data, and then stop it, but this is inefficient. It is far faster to use an AsyncTask that will run once, return the data, and be done.

If you need to be continually doing something in the background, though, a Service is your best bet. Examples of this include playing music, continually checking for new data, etc.

For the most part, Services are for when you want to run code even when your application's Activity isn't open. AsyncTasks are designed to make executing code off of the UI thread incredibly simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AutoCompleteTextView` and `ContentProvider` to do your implementation. Save your string array in database and access them by `Cursor` to popup and show in `AutoCompleteTextView`. There is an example available in the [official document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView looks promising. When you say store string array in database do you mean like a SQlite database?

Comment: yes, store the data in sqlite database. Android will do the auto complete for you, that will save your lot of time.